# How to add XPM tags for component linked field and embedded fields in DXA 1.2

Tags: 2013-sp1, dxa, experience-manager, embedded-items

I have three Schemas as per Schemas design created the model

1st model : `NewsletterContainer` having normal field and component link field allowed Newsletter content schema

2nd model : `Newsletter` having normal fields and embedded field i.e. embedded to _Newsletter embedded schema
3rd Model : `_Newsletter` embedded having normal fields

```
[SemanticEntity(Vocab = "www.sdl.com/web/schemas/core", EntityName = "NewsletterContainer", Prefix = "nlc", Public = true)] 
public class NewsletterContainer : EntityModel
{
    [SemanticProperty("nlc:date")]
    public string Date { get; set; }

    [SemanticProperty("nlc:newsletter_components")] 
    public List<Newsletter> Newsletter_Components { get; set; }
}


[SemanticEntity(Vocab = "www.sdl.com/web/schemas/core", EntityName = "Newsletter", Prefix = "nsl", Public = true)] 
public class Newsletter : EntityModel
{
    [SemanticProperty("nsl:title")] 
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [SemanticProperty("nsl:newsletter")] 
    public List<_Newsletter> News_letter { get; set; }
}

[SemanticEntity(Vocab = "www.sdl.com/web/schemas/core", EntityName = "Newsletter", Prefix = "nsl", Public = true)] 
public class _Newsletter : EntityModel
{
    [SemanticProperty("nsl:text")] 
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [SemanticProperty("nsl:image")] 
    public Image Image_Link { get; set; }
}
```

Entity View code:

```
@if (Model != null)
{
  <div class="newsletter" @Html.DxaEntityMarkup()>
    <div class="title-date">
      <div @Html.DxaPropertyMarkup(() => Model.Date)>
        <p class="date">@String.Format("{0:MMM. dd, yyyy}", Convert.ToDateTime(Model.Date))</p>
      </div>            
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Newsletter, Top Bar -->
    <div class="newsletter-top-bar">
      <!-- Main header jump nav -->
      <ul @Html.DxaPropertyMarkup(() => Model.Newsletter_Components)>
        <!-- Output all main headers. Jump Section -->
        @for (int index = 0; index < @Model.Newsletter_Components.Count; index++)
        {
          if (Model.Newsletter_Components[index].Title != null)
          {
            <li @Html.DxaPropertyMarkup(() => Model.Newsletter_Components[index].Title)><a href='@string.Format("#section{0}", (index+1).ToString())'>@Model.Newsletter_Components[index].Title</a></li>                                                 
          }
        }
        <!-- /Output all main headers -->
      </ul>
      <!-- /Main header jump nav -->
    </div>
    <!-- /Newsletter, Top Bar -->
    <!-- Subsection Jump Nav -->
    <div class="newsletter-jumpnav third-menu">
      <!-- Subsection Jump Navigation loop -->
      @for (int index = 0; index < @Model.Newsletter_Components.Count; index++)
      {
        <div class="newsletter-jumpnav-block">
          @if (Model.Newsletter_Components[index].Title != null)
          {
            <div @Html.DxaPropertyMarkup(() => Model.Newsletter_Components[index].Title)>
              <h2>@Model.Newsletter_Components[index].Title</h2>
            </div>                  
          }
        </div>
      }
      </div>
      <hr />
      <!-- /Subsection Jump Nav -->
      <!-- Newsletter Main Content -->
      <div class="newsletter-content">
        <!-- Section Title Loop-->
        @for (int index = 0; index < @Model.Newsletter_Components.Count; index++)
        {
          <div class="newsletter-content-title">
            <!-- Section Title-->
            @if (Model.Newsletter_Components[index].Title != null)
            {
              <a href="#" name='@string.Format("section{0}",(index+1).ToString())'></a>
              <div @Html.DxaPropertyMarkup(() => Model.Newsletter_Components[index].Title)>
                <h2>@Model.Newsletter_Components[index].Title</h2>
              </div>                                               
            }
          </div>
          <!-- Each Section Title Content-->
          for (int subIndex = 0; subIndex < @Model.Newsletter_Components[index].News_letter.Count; subIndex++)
          {
            <div class="rtf">
              <!-- Each Section Title Content Image or Not Check-->
              @if (Model.Newsletter_Components[index].News_letter[subIndex].Image_Link != null)
              {
                <div class="article">
                  <div @Html.DxaPropertyMarkup(() => Model.Newsletter_Components[index].News_letter[subIndex].Image_Link)>
                    <img src="@Model.Newsletter_Components[index].News_letter[subIndex].Image_Link.Url" alt="@Model.Newsletter_Components[index].News_letter[subIndex].Image_Link.Alternate_Text" class="image" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="article-content">
                    <h2>Article, Image Left</h2>
                    <hr class="article-underline" />
                    <div class="rtf">
                      @if (Model.Newsletter_Components[index].News_letter[subIndex].Text != null)
                      {
                        <div @Html.DxaPropertyMarkup(() => Model.Newsletter_Components[index].News_letter[subIndex].Text)>
                          @Html.DxaRichText(@Model.Newsletter_Components[index].News_letter[subIndex].Text)
                        </div>
                      }
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              }
              else
              {
                if (Model.Newsletter_Components[index].News_letter[subIndex].Text != null)
                {
                  <div @Html.DxaPropertyMarkup(() => Model.Newsletter_Components[index].News_letter[subIndex].Text)>
                    @Html.DxaRichText(@Model.Newsletter_Components[index].News_letter[subIndex].Text)
                  </div>
                }
              }
            </div>
          </div>
        }
      }
    </div>
    <!-- /Newsletter Main Content -->
  </div>
}
```

We are getting editable option to `NewsletterContainer` model only for the `Date` field and not getting the edit option for List or Linked Components.

The Linked Components like `Newsletter` and `_Newsletter` are not editable.

Enable Inline Editing is checked for all the fields in all three Schemas.

Comment: Can you share the actual markup that is outputted from the view, so an extract from the source view of the HTML, that should contain the XPM markup, and as Sayantan asked for, some details of the view showing if the correct `@Html.DxaPropertyMarkup` calls are there?

Comment: Could you please udate the view details as well? Ensure whether the "Enable In Line Editing" option is checked for that particular field in the schema.Also confirm are you trying to bind same schema with 2 different model ?

Comment: BTW: You are using very confusing/ambiguous View Model types. Why do you have two types with almost the same name and exactly the same semantics?

Comment: Newsletter is content schema and _Newsletter is embedded schema there we are using semantic entity and semantic property for Newsletter and _Newsletter model. Newsletter container is content schema which is having component link field allowed schema is Newsletter content schema

Comment: As per your above .cshtml code for Render multi-valued embedded fields you can use    <div @Html.DxaPropertyMarkup(() => Model.Newsletter_Components,index)><h2>@Model.Newsletter_Components[index].Title</h2>
                        </div> 
inside for loop

Comment: @K951 Can you please ensure whether the "Enable In Line Editing" option is checked for that particular field in the schema ?

Comment: @SayantanBasu Yup it is enabled for that field also

Comment: For clarity: the "Enable inline editing" flag has no impact on DXA; in DXA all fields are  potentially inline editable and the Entity View determines which field/properties are actually inline editable by means of the `@Html.DxaPropertyMarkup()` helper.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the DXAPropertyMarkup in the right place. As you are using multiple linked component field, so I will suggest you to add markup in the div immediately after the for loop -

it will be something like [Sample Code] -

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.LinkedComponent.Count; i++)
            {
                LinkedComponentModel linkedComponent = Model.LinkedComponent[i];

                <div @Html.DxaPropertyMarkup(() => Model.LinkedComponent, i)>
                    <span @Html.DxaPropertyMarkup(() => linkedComponent.LinkText)>@linkedComponent.LinkText</span>
                </div>
            }
```